# Highlight font if it is minimum or maximum of the last 5 years in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a matrix in SSRS to show order quantity of different products for the last 5 years.
I want to set the font color of the products field based on the total orders of the last year.
For instance, if the order quantity of the last year is the highest order quantity recorded within the last 5 years I want the font to be "green". If the order quantity is the lowest in the last 5 years then "red". If the order quantity it neither the lowest nor highest then black.

I have tried using the example form this blog.

[www.bigator.com/2012/04/26/spothighlight-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-each-row-in-matrix-report-in-ssrs/](http://www.bigator.com/2012/04/26/spothighlight-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-each-row-in-matrix-report-in-ssrs/)

I have modified the expression to include the year for my case but its not working.

Is there something I am missing?

Can someone please help.

This is the expression I have tried for the font color.

```
=SWITCH((Fields!OrderQuantity.Value=ReportItems!MaxQty.Value) and (Fields!CalendarYear.Value="2007"),"Green",
        (Fields!OrderQuantity.Value=ReportItems!MinQty.Value) and (Fields!CalendarYear.Value="2007"),"Red",
        (((Fields!OrderQuantity.Value<ReportItems!MaxQty.Value) and (Fields!CalendarYear.Value="2007")) OR
        (Fields!OrderQuantity.Value>ReportItems!MinQty.Value) and (Fields!CalendarYear.Value="2007")),"White")
```

I am expecting the Product category font to be "green" because 2007 recorded the highest order quantity. but it is not working.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your report design, including the row and column groups structure (the bit just below the main report design surface). It sounds like you are over complicating things and hard coding values which will change over time is never a good thing. In a simplified version only highlighting the max number it would just need something like `=IIF(SUM(Fields!Qty.Value) = SUM(Fields!Qty.Value, "myRowGroupName"), "Red", "Black")`

Comment: So what happens when the Calendar year field _isn't_ 2007?  You're specifying that you want the min and max for the last 5 years, but this will consistently only work if the year is 2007.

Comment: I was hardcoding "2007" for test purposes because that year contains data for the different scenarios I was testing.

Comment: Thanks Alan and Steve. I was able to figure it out. The problem was with how I was enclosing the brackets of the expression.